# order by Popularity spotify API search resulte

Tags: javascript, json, api, spotify

I have this **search function** to show the search results on my website.
I really want the search results to order by **Popularity**, so the most popular are **first on the list**.

I know how to the popularity of the song out from the **API 
( +data.tracks.items[i].popularity+ )** but I have no idea how to get the **order_by** to work.

```
function searchSpotify(){
  $('#search-container').html("");
  var q = $("#query").val();

  var spotifyAPI = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q="+q+"&type=track&market=DK";
  $.getJSON( spotifyAPI, {
    format: "json"
  }).done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data.tracks.items);
    for (var i = data.tracks.items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var item = data.tracks.items[i];
      $('#search-container').append('<div class="video"><img src='+data.tracks.items[i].album.images[0].url+'><div class="info"><h3>'+data.tracks.items[i].name+'</h3><h5>'+data.tracks.items[i].artists[0].name+' <a href="'+data.tracks.items[i].artists[0].external_urls.spotify+'">!</a></h5><h5>'+data.tracks.items[i].album.name+'</h5><br><h3>Popularity: '+data.tracks.items[i].popularity+'</h3><audio controls="" name="media"><source src="'+data.tracks.items[i].preview_url+'"></audio><div class="add-video" data-id="'+data.tracks.items[i].uri+'" onclick="" data-title="'+data.tracks.items[i].name+'">Add to queue</div></div></div>');
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are going to have to use some old school sorting methods. Good exercise to keep your coding sharp! :)

Comment: yearh, the problem is just that I dont know how :)

Comment: What data type is the popularity?